# Need Customize Gson deserialization, need only single element JSON, to Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have: Json:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "name": "John",
  "id_client": "2",
  ...
 }
```

My class:

```
public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name; 
    private Client client;
    ...
}

public class Client{
  private int id;
}
```

How i deserialize id_client: "2", to a Client object and set id(CLient) ?

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: Your Json is invalid.

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao - How so?

Comment: I'd just parse the JSON and create the objects.  You'd have the job done already if you did that, vs looking for a way to do it "automatically".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ...
    Map<String,Object> parsed = jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
    Person thePerson = new Person(parsed);
    ...    

public class Person {
    ...
    public Person(Map<String,Object> parsed) {
        id = Integer.getInteger(parsed.getString("id"));
        name = parsed.getString("name");
        int idClient = Integer.getInteger(parsed.getString("id_client"));
        client = new Client(idClient);
    }
    ...
}
```